# Key retention | Retrieving old keys

Tags: azure-keyvault

Anyone know how long Azure Keyvault retains old keys? The scenario would be an on-prem SQL server VM using keyvault for TDE with keys being rotated regularly.

If we were to restore an old snapshot of the SQL server, will it be able to access the old, retired key?

Answer (score -1):

Soft deleted resources are retained for a set period of time, **90 days**.

Upon deleting a key vault object, such as a key, the service will place the object in a deleted state, making it inaccessible to any retrieval operations. While in this state, the key vault object can only be listed, recovered, or forcefully/permanently deleted.

At the same time, Key Vault will schedule the deletion of the underlying data corresponding to the deleted key vault or key vault object for execution after a predetermined retention interval. The DNS record corresponding to the vault is also retained for the duration of the retention interval.

> Use a key without an expiration date – and don't set an expiration date on a key already in use: once the key expires, the encrypted databases lose access to their TDE Protector and are inaccessible within 24 hours.

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-ovw-soft-delete) and this [one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/transparent-data-encryption-byok-azure-sql).